# Computing the value of a function based on the geometric series of 1/2^n

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometric-series

So in John B. Conway's First Course in Analysis Book we're told to consider the interval $[a,b],$ and let $\{r_n\}$ denote a sequence of all rationals in said interval. Next, we define a map $\alpha:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$\alpha(t)=\sum_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\r_n<t}}\dfrac{1}{2^n}.$$
Totally fine with that definition. Where I'm confused is when he says that $\alpha(b)=1.$ If $b$ is irrational surely that would be the case as $\alpha(b)$ would just be a geometric sum which converges to $1$. If $b$ is rational, however, it seems like $\alpha(b)$ would never be $1$. Consider $r_n=b$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence $\alpha(b)=1-1/2^n<1.$ So I'm confused as to why Conway says it's $1$. Could anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the context of the question, but could it be possible that $\{r_n\}$ is to be a sequence of all rationals in $(a,b)$ rather than $[a, b]$?

Comment: I agree with what you say. Is the interval really closed? Also just to be sure,is the sequence rn supposed to be a bijection?

Comment: You know, Conway doesn't really specify. However, I've deduced that the interval must be closed, as we call it $J$ with implicit endpoints $a,b$. We define $\alpha:J\to\mathbb{R}$. We then ask for $\alpha(a),\alpha(b)$ so already seems implied the interval is closed. 

Next, we're given that it is discontinuous at each rational. This implies we mean to choose the $r_n$ from the closed interval, as otherwise we have no right Jump discontinuity at $a$.

Comment: Just sum over $r_n\leq t$ if you prefer. This gives a cadlag function

Comment: @Federico I thought about that, only Conway also claims we have $\alpha(a)=0$, which fails if we change it to $r_n\leq t$ when $a$ is rational.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't really matter, just take $\{r_n\}$ to be $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$

Comment: My suggestion to using $r_n\leq t$ is because it gives the more common definition of cumulative distribution function of a measure $\mu((-\infty,t])$

Comment: where $\mu = \sum_{n} \tfrac1{2^n}\delta_{r_n}$

Comment: @Fredrico that's not what Conway wrote, and doing so cause the sequence to fail to meet other conditions that Conway demands of it.

Comment: Then write to Conway. I don't know what else to say. The "mistake" is easily fixable in several ways and it's clear what the example is trying to demonstrate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86156/discussion-between-melody-and-federico).

Comment: It doesn't seem a major bug in the exercise. Since the text is clearly incorrect, just fix it however you want and you will be good to go. Then you can also compare the differences, for instance summing over $r_n<t$ or $r_n\leq t$